# MySQL:Fill temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Table1 .For more [[details]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b49) 
I am trying to do a couple of things :

```
- Get table T2 which have the same fields 
 - T2 contains rows from Table1 on responding on the following conditions :
 - If the difference between the start date and end date for two different rows and for the same id is less than 3 so  end date gets the value of the start date else this row will be inserted in T2
```

I tried to implement it

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempabsences  LIKE absences;
    INSERT INTO tempabsences(id ,utilisateurs_id,date_debut,tempabsences.date_fin,type,statut)
    SELECT absences.utilisateurs_id ,absences.utilisateurs_id,absences.date_debut,absences.date_fin,absences.type,absences.statut
    FROM absences 
    ORDER BY absences.date_debut ASC, absences.utilisateurs_id ASC
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tempabsences.date_fin=IF(abs(DATEDIFF(tempabsences.date_fin,absences.date_debut)<=3) ,absences.date_fin,tempabsences.date_fin),
                tempabsences.date_debut=IF(abs(DATEDIFF(tempabsences.date_fin,absences.date_debut)<=3) ,tempabsences.date_debut,absences.date_debut),
                tempabsences.utilisateurs_id=absences.utilisateurs_id , 
                tempabsences.id=IF(abs(DATEDIFF(tempabsences.date_fin,absences.date_debut)<=3),tempabsences.id,(select MAX(absences.utilisateurs_id)from absences )+absences.id )
```

The query don't respond on conditions , it update the row and don't insert it .

Comment: What keys do you have on the tables?

Comment: Use INSERT IGNORE INTO in your syntax.

Comment: One remark, it seems a bit unlikely that it will update any rows as it is a new temp table and therefore dont have any rows. Seems to me a simple CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempabsence SELECT....

Comment: @KayNelson il I use simply select , how can I in this case do a comparaison between the rows already inserted in tempabsences and absences ?